# Average lines of a file if they are similar

Tags: python, file-io

I have a file containing data to be plotted but the curve is not smooth due to issue during the profile extraction (see attached picture).[image: plot of column 1 as function of column 2].

I would like to average the data when necessary to obtain a smooth curve. For instance, a solution could be:
if the relative error between the first column of line n and line n+1 is inferior to 0.01% then replace lines n and n+1 by a single line which take the average of the of lines n and n+1 for column 1 and column 2.

I would like this code to be in Python.
I started with this code :

```
file1 = open('filename')

Lines = file1.readlines()
for j in Lines:
    for i in j.split(','):
        #if the relative error on the 1st column between line j and line j+1 is below 0.01% then
            # replace line j and j+1 by a single line that contains the averaged value of column 1 on the first column and the averaged value of column 2 on the second column
```

Here is an example of what I have :

```
0       0
1       10
2       19
2.001   22
3       29
3.001   31.1
4       40
5       50
6       60
```

Here is what I would like to obtain:

```
0   0
1   10
2   20.5
3   30.05
4   40
5   50
6   60
```

How can I do this?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Please show your code, explain why and how it failed, and show also your expected output for your example input.

Comment: I updated the post with my code and an example of what I have and what I would like to obtain. My main issues is that I do not manage to access to lines and columns. For instance: how to get column 2 of line j+1 when we are at line j in the for loop? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution so I post it if it can help:

```
        with open('filename', "r") as f:      
            lines = f.readlines()
            newlines=[]
            n=1
            while n < len(lines)-1:
                if (float(lines[n+1].split(',')[0])-float(lines[n].split(',')[0]))/float(lines[n].split(',')[0]) >= epsilon:
                    newlines.append([float(lines[n].split(',')[0])] + [float(lines[n].split(',')[1])])
                    n=n+1
                else:
                    jj=1
                    sum0=0
                    sum1=0
                    while (float(lines[n+jj].split(',')[0])-float(lines[n].split(',')[0]))/float(lines[n].split(',')[0]) < epsilon:
                        sum0=sum0+float(lines[n+jj].split(',')[0])
                        sum1=sum1+float(lines[n+jj].split(',')[1])
                        jj=jj+1
                    newlines.append([(sum0+float(lines[n].split(',')[0]))/(jj)] + [(sum1+float(lines[n].split(',')[1]))/(jj)])
                    n=n+jj
            print('----------')
        
        with open('filename', "w") as f:     
            for ligne in newlines:
                f.write(','.join(str(x) for x in ligne) + '\n')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).